# Laravel 5 - Cookies not present

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

I'm doing a `laravel` app but when I try to create an account it gives a `csrf` error..

When I check what cookies the website have, I find that I have no cookies, there should be a `XSFR-TOKEN` and a `laravel_session cookies`, but laravel is not generating any of those cookies, so it gives me a token not found when i try to create an account.. anyone know why it does that? any idea how to fix that?

Also just installed a new clean `laravel` and find out if I put the "app" view inside of a folder it also happends and doesnt generate the `cookies`, I have tried to change the folder permissions but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Open your http app/Http/Kernel.php file and check if your Kernel::$middleware array contains:

- Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies
- Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse
- Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession (this is middleware which is responsible for passing data to session driver in Laravel 5)
- Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession
- App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken

To clarify - Kernel::$middleware array contains middleware which is executed on every HTTP request. By default it contains middleware that is essential for session support in Laravel. Perhaphs you accidentaly deleted them.

Here is original file: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.22/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: Hello, yes its just like in the original file :/

Comment: I found out my problem! i was doing a @endsection that was wrong.